# How to do partitioning in combination with Service Fabric Remoting

Tags: c#, azure, service-fabric-stateful, azure-service-fabric

Let's say, I'm using Azure Service Fabric Stateful Service, with RemotingV2, and I want to store users phone numbers (That's the only thing my service does).

```
Task StoreNumber(string username, string phoneNumber);
Task<string> GetNumber(string username);
```

I want to use the username for partitioning.

What's the elegant way to do that?

can I remove the `username` parameter from the methods and somehow get it from the request?

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: You want to use the whole username as a partition? It seems you are storing just one number per user (given getnumber returns one number for a given username), is that correct?

Comment: @PeterBons 1. its just an example. But, I'm going to be storing multiple entries per user.2. I intend on using the hashing partitioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/fN9zQm_FVVw) that covers this subject and here's a [working code sample](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Dictionary) that goes with it.

- use a (proper e.g. FNV) hash algorithm to get the hash of `username`, use the `long` result to determine an `Int64RangePartition` by its key.
- use a gateway that does the hashing for you (e.g. api management, or a custom stateless service) and forwards the call
- you could use [customer headers](https://github.com/Expecho/ServiceFabric-Remoting-CustomHeaders) to pass the `username`. (the sample doesn't)

Comment: That's the general direction we thought of as well. Thanks.